# Format columns with numbers right aligned and with fixed decimals

Tags: task-list, json, column-formatting

I successfully added conditional coloring of cells in a column of a custom list using JSON.

So I have browsed several resources at M$ for formatting options. 
E.g. [column-formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

I wasn't able to find any possibility to display numbers right flushed. Additionaly I want to display only the integer part of a float. How can I do that?

Bonus: How can I display a number in exponential form e.g. \$2.345\cdot10^{12}\$ (it's a pity tex formatting doesn't work here)

**Update**
Here's my current json code:

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
 "elmType": "div",
 "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField < 10000, 'sp-field-severity--good', if(@currentField < 300000, 'sp-field-severity--low', if(@currentField < 2000000, 'sp-field-severity--warning', if(@currentField < 20000000, 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', 'sp-field-severity--blocked'))))+ ' ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary'"
  },
 "children": [
    {
     "elmType": "span",
     "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
       },
     "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField <= 70,'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

The first elmType isn't relevant, it's a relic from the sample code where I started :)

Comment: For both, you basically need to add css styles to your json formatter.  If you can post your current JSON, we can assist with how to add the styles you need.

Comment: @willman: I added my code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To align your cell to the right you can modify the last bit of your JSON:

```
{
 "elmType": "span",
   "style": {
     "width": "100%",
     "text-align": "right"
   },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

To get **just** the integer bit you could do the following:
Adjust for correct decimal sign...

```
"txtContent": "=if(indexOf(toString(@currentField),'.')>=0,substring(toString(@currentField),0,indexOf(toString(@currentField),'.')),@currentField)"
```

You also have the `ceiling` or `floor` functions, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a `round`or `int`function.

The bonus-bit I will have to leave for someone else!

Comment: This looks very good. And as the column is already a calculated column, I realised I can do the rounding in the column calculation field using the "ROUND(epression,0)" function.